# Alpha in Hype, Processing

Tags: processing, alpha

I am generating a hexagon particle pattern for a design project in Processing, HYPE (see sample below).

My problem is that I cannot produce a visible alpha variations, like [here](http://www.hypeframework.org/examples/HGridLayout/example_003/index.html), even with the same chunk of alpha code. Googling doesn't help. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

My code is [here](https://github.com/glitchyzoe/HexGlit/blob/master/build.pde).

Thank you.

[image: generated particles without alpha]

Answer (score 1):

You're using web notation to define your colors, which doesn't support transparency. Instead, use one of the `color()` functions that take an alpha channel.

```
colors = new HColorPool()
    .add(color(#32184E, 100))
    //...
```

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html):

> Web color notation only works for opaque colors. To define a color with an alpha value, you can either use `color()` or hexadecimal notation. For hex notation, prefix the values with `0x`, for instance `color c = 0xCC006699`. In that example, `CC` (the hex value of 204) is the alpha value, and the remainder is identical to a web color. Note that in hexadecimal notation, the alpha value appears in the first position. (The alpha value appears last when used within color(), fill(), and stroke().) The following is an equivalent way of writing the preceding example, but using `color()` and specifying the alpha value as its second parameter: `color c = color(#006699, 191)`

For future reference, you should post your code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in your question instead of posting a link to it.

Comment: Thank you! About the code — duly noted. In fact, I am looking for a way to randomize the opacity, would you recommend a specific way to do that or I should just do .add(color(#ffffff, 30)),  .add(color(#ffffff, 60)) and so on? It somehow works in Josh's code with .alpha( (int)random(30, 100)). But not in mine.

Comment: Can you be more specific than saying it doesn't work? What exactly does that code do? You also might consider posting a new question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note that this shouldn't be your whole sketch, just a small example to demonstrate what's not working).

Comment: Yes, okay. I'll do the new question with MCVE trying to be more specific. Thank you!